# Is it possible to serve data from a static JSON file using an API Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically my question is the title. Right now there are only a few items I need to serve, but I am trying to avoid having to create a separate view for each item in my MVC 4 app. Basically it would look something like this:

**/Content/Services.json (or something)**

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "Reverse Unit Pump Service",
"description": "lorem ipsum dolar...",
"image_url": "image.jpg"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Fishing Operations",
"description": "lorem ipsum dolar...",
"image_url": "image.jpg"
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Wench Truck Services",
"description": "lorem ipsum dolar...",
"image_url": "image.jpg"
}
]
```

And I would like to use an API controller to serve up some Service Objects (e.g.):

**/Models/Service.cs**

```
namespace Production_Downhole.Models
{
    public class Service
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
        public string Description;
        public string ImageURL;
    }
}
```

How do I set that up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize it to your object and return it from your controller.

http://www.tomasvera.com/programming/using-javascriptserializer-to-parse-json-objects/